# Extract paragraph or sentence from pdf azure cognitive search

Tags: azure-blob-storage, azure-cognitive-search

I am having a blob container where I am storing PDF files and I am using Azure cognitive search to search word or content over pdf. When searching a word or sentence which is present in one of the pdf present in the container, Azure cognitive search is returning the entire content present in the pdf.

- Is there a way that we can extract only a sentence or paragraph from pdf where the word or sentence is appearing?
- Is there a way to highlight the input passed wherever it appears in pdf?
- Am I using the correct service for above two points?

Comment: Did you find a way to extract only a paragraph or sentence containing search term?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a feature exactly for what you are looking for, see [highlight](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-pagination-page-layout#hit-highlighting)
you only need to highlight the Content field

```
POST /indexes/hotels-sample-index/docs/search?api-version=2020-06-30 
    {  
      "search": "sandy beaches",  
      "highlight": "Content"
    }
```

Comment: this answers only a part as how to highlight search term. Is there a way to extract only a paragraph or sentence containing search term?

Comment: Well I believe highlighting the content is the only option. It won't return you just the required paragraph.